# Counting number of words and unique words from txt file- Python

Tags: python, file, text, strip

I am attempting to read a text file, strip the punctuation, make everything lower case, then print the total number of words, the total number of unique words (meaning that "a" for instance, if it is in the text 20 times, will only be counted once), then print the most frequently occuring words along with their frequency (i.e. a:20).

I realize there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but I am a beginner and am trying to solve this problem using a minimal number of imports, and was wondering if there is a way to code this and not import something like Collections.

I have my code below, but I do not understand why I am not getting the answer that I need. This code is printing the entirety of the text file (with each word on a new line, and all punctuation removed), then printing:

```
e 1
n 1
N 1
o 1
```

Which, I assume, is "None" split into characters with their frequency. Why is my code giving me this answer and what can I do to change it?

Code below:

```
file=open("C:\\Users\\Documents\\AllSonnets.txt", "r")


def strip_sonnets():
    import string
    new_file=file.read().split()
    for words in new_file:
        data=words.translate(string.punctuation)
        data=data.lower()
        data=data.strip(".")
        data=data.strip(",")
        data=data.strip("?")
        data=data.strip(";")
        data=data.strip("!")
        data=data.replace("'","")
        data=data.replace('"',"")
        data=data.strip(":")
        print(data)

new_file=strip_sonnets()
new_file=str(new_file)

count={}
for w in new_file:
    if w in count:
        count[w] += 1
    else:
        count[w] = 1
for word, times in count.items():
    print (word, times)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want translate if you want to just remove punctuation from the ends of the words. a `collections.Counter` dict  will also count the words for you:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation


with open("in.txt") as f:       
    c = Counter(word.http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29328942/editrstrip(punctuation) for line in f for  word in line.lower().split())

# print each word and how many times it appears
for k, freq in c.items():
   print(k,freq)
```

To see the words in order of most frequent to least then you can use `.most_common()`:

```
for k,v in c.most_common():
    print(k,v)
```

Without  imports use `dict.get`:

```
c = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.lower().split():
            key = word.rstrip(punctuation)
            c[key] = c.get(key, 0) + 1
```

Then to sort by frequency:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for k,v in sorted(c.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    print(k,v)
```

Why you see None is because you set `new_file=strip_sonnets()` and your function returns nothing so as with all functions that don't specify a return value it returns `None` by default.

You then set `new_file=str(new_file)` so when you iterate over `for w in new_file` you are iterating over each character in `None`

You need to return the data:

```
def strip_sonnets():
    new_file=file.read().split()
    for words in new_file:
        data= words.translate(string.punctuation)
        data=data.lower()
        data=data.strip(".")
        data=data.strip(",")
        data=data.strip("?")
        data=data.strip(";")
        data=data.strip("!")
        data=data.replace("'","")
        data=data.replace('"',"")
        data=data.strip(":")
    return data # return
```

I would simplify your function to returning a generator expression which returns all the words stripped of punctuation and lowered:

```
 path = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\AllSonnets.txt"

def strip_sonnets():
    with open(path, "r") as f:     
        return (word.lower().rstrip(punctuation) for line in f for word in line.split())
```

`.rstrip(punctuation)` is basically doing what you are trying to do with you code using strip and replace repeatedly.

Comment: @NizamMohamed, probably because of your code dump. You have not answered the question, you have simply dumped code.